# Testing Cypress with Angularjs. Problem with value in nd-model/data-ng-change

Tags: cypress

I have a problem with cypress and how to do the test of an input type = file. I have the following html;

and what I want is to be able to invoke the function of the data-ng-change so that it is executed by passing the parameter or filling in the value of the ng-model = "vm.newfile"

It runs inside an iframe

cy.wrap($body).find('# docEncargo1').as.(docencargo)

I have injected angular but to execute the following;

```
        const getElementScope = (selector) =>
            cy.get(selector)
             .then($el =>
               getAngular()
                 .then(ng => ng.element($el).scope())
             )
```

the value of ng.element($el).scope() is undefined.

Can you help me and tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

Thanks

Comment: I wonder if the iframe is part of the issue. Can you show us your HTML, and your selector?

Comment: Hi Maccurt, 
I attached html and controller ;Html

Thank you so much

Comment: <div ng-hide="((vm.AdjuntarDocumento=='false') ||(vm.idSeleccionado == false))" class="fileUpload btn btn-primary fill-orange1 text-orange5">
       Adjuntar documento firma
       <input type='file'   id="docEncargo1" ng-click="clear()"   class="upload" ng-change="vm.adjuntaDocEncargo(vm.newfile)"  ng-model="vm.newfile" base-sixty-four-input accept="application/pdf">
 </div>

Comment: angular.module('DcmApp').controller('ModalVerEncargoCtrl', function (DcmAceptarDocumentoIn,DcmRechazarDocumentoIn,DcmEncargosMediadorIn,$filter,$log,$window,$uibModalInstance, $scope,$rootScope,DcmServiceFacade,  DcmDocumentosConsIn, NgTableParams, DcmAdjuntarDocumentoIn,DcmDescargarDocumentoIn,DcmFirmantesDocumentoIn,base64,DcmObtenerEnlaceFirmaIn,$uibModal,APP_CONFIG) {
  var vm=this;
  
  vm.adjuntaDocEncargo = function (fullPathNewFile) {
  .
  .
  .
 }
 })